# System.InvalidOperationException: 'The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.'

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2022, ms-jet-ace

I am simply trying to connect to an MS Access database which is on my local computer.

I am using Visual Studio 2022, my system is 64-bit, my MS Office is also 64-bit. I have the "Database Engine 2016 Redistributable-x64" installed on my computer.

If I connect to the database manually clicking under Tools tab: "Connect to Database" it is working and connects, however if I try to code it, it fails:

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=testapp.accdb");
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            con.Open();
```

Thanks in advance for anyone helping me out here!

Comment: And your application is running as 64-bit?

Comment: In build settings for the project, do you have target as X86, or maybe AnyCPU + "Prefer 32bit" is ticked?

Comment: Thanks guys. I have it set as "AnyCPU". Should that not work, is x64 preferable ?
However: by downloading the Access Database Engine 2016 (32-bit) and install it on top of the 64-bit engine as a 'passive' installation, I made it worked. So, probably the application is now running as 32-bit after all.

Comment: EDIT: I changed now to "x64", it won't run anymore. It throws the "System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException: 'External component has thrown an exception.'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution is to change the active solution platform from `AnyCPU` to `x64` under *Debug* in the Configuration Manager.

Alternatively, I had it running while set as `AnyCPU`, by installing the *Access Database Engine 2016 (32-bit)* on top of the 64-bit version as a *quiet* or *passive* installation.

Thanks everyone for helping.